# SoapUI JDBC Request Step - [Error 3706] [SQLState 42000] Syntax error: Data Type does not match a Defined Type name

Tags: jdbc, soapui

I am new to SoapUI. In JDBC Request Step, I am getting the below error while trying to retrieve data responses from a Teradata database using the below SQL query which converts the transfer property (PERSID) data type to Integer that is the defined data type of this field in Teradata. I have tried all sort of data type conversion but the same sort of errors occurred.
I am hoping someone might be able to help me resolve this? Thanks.

```
SELECT MDCR_NMBR FROM   EDW_DEV_ODS_IMMN_DB.CHLD_LOC_T WHERE PRSNL_ID=:cast(PERSID as int)
```

*INFO:Error getting response for [Teradata JDBC Request]; java.sql.SQLException: [Teradata Database] [TeraJDBC 17.00.00.02] [Error 3706] [SQLState 42000] Syntax error: Data Type "PERSID" does not match a Defined Type name.*

However, if I set the value of the transfer property = 200000114 and SQL query = (SELECT MDCR_NMBR FROM EDW_DEV_ODS_IMMN_DB.CHLD_LOC_T WHERE PRSNL_ID=:PERSID) then it all works fine.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oVP0a.png)

Comment: Maybe it should be `cast(PERSID as integer)`? A quick look at the teradata documentation suggests that it doesn't know `INT` as an alias for `INTEGER`.

Comment: Thanks. I have also tried cast(PERSID as integer) and the same error still occurred :-(

Comment: What is the actual type of `PERSID`?